# Which Spider-Man is he?

Tags: comics, marvel, spider-man

This concerns the identity of *a* Spider-Man in the new 5-issue miniseries [Spider-Men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Men). Spoiler text to protect the innocent:

> In the first issue we follow Peter Parker as he does his New York thing, then gets warped into an alternate universe and meets the new Ultimate Spider-Man, Miles Morales. But which Peter Parker is it? He sounds too young to be the Peter Parker of the main continuity (which I had at first assumed him to be) with what seems to be inexperience and all his talk about girl problems. Or is this a Peter Parker from a new continuity? Is it even Peter Parker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The claim is the Peter Parker showing up in the Ultimate Universe crossover, Spidermen, IS the canon Marvel Earth-616 Spiderman.**

From an [interview](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=38080) with Alex Alonso, editor-in-chief:

> On the other side, there's "our" Peter from the original 616 universe. There's a million ways to play him seeing a universe like the Ultimate U from awestruck to scared. What were the things you had to get out of this character confronting his own death?
>
> Oh boy, Brian would kill me if I spilled those beans! [Laughter] Let's just say we've considered all the questions a fanboy could ask.

[image: Promotional Cover for Spidermen]

[CBR: ALONSO ON MARVEL'S ULTIMATE "SPIDER-MEN" CROSSOVER](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=38080)

Comment: That was my impression as well. But the PP in the book read like a much younger version of the 616 PP, or maybe I'm mistaken?

Comment: The writers have probably not read Spiderman in a while (so many of them have NEVER read an issue BEFORE they start writing it, so there may be a bit of an archetype being used rather than the character as we have known him today. Trust me I hate when writers have NEVER read a copy of a book before they start writing it. And that happens a lot more than you think.